# How do I remove/add the python interpreter from eclipse?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, interpreter

I'm an eclipse noob.

After adding PyDev to eclipse, I try to create a "PyDev Django Project", but and I get the "Django not found" error.

I heard that you have to remove the python interpreter from eclipse, then add it again.  But I don't know how to do that.

Can someone show me how to remove/add the python interpreter in eclipse?

It is greatly appreciated.

Brent.

Answer (score 0):

On the menubar go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Pydev` -> `Interpreters` -> `Python`

Remove the interpreter and click on `Quick Auto Config`.

That should do the trick. Make sure django is installed first.